# Recalled message in Outlook VBA declaration

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to find out what the data type for a recalled message holds in Outlook.

When defining Mail Items any Recalled Messages are not included as they are not regarded as being a mail item. Below is the line of code for declaring a mail item variable

```
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
```

Does anyone know what the correct way to declare a Recalled Message?

Answer (score 2):

To recall Sent Items - Select Email in your Sent folder and run the following [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

```
Option Explicit
Sub Recall()
  Dim SendItem As Object
  Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector

  '// Selected item in Sent Items folder
  Set SendItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

  If TypeName(SendItem) = "MailItem" Then
    Set olItem = SendItem
    Set olInsp = olItem.GetInspector
    '// Execute Recall command button
    With olInsp
      .Display
      .CommandBars.FindControl(, 2511).Execute
      .Close olDiscard
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me in 2010.  I set it up to work on the current selection of messages to batch-recall a number at a time.  the only minor issue is that it throws up a dialogue box for each message asking if you want to delete or replace the message.

Comment: it was not working for me, I changed the command to .commandbars.executemso("RecallThisMessage"), now it works but for every recall it shows a popup to ask whether to recall only or recall and replace. I wish there was a programmatic way to recall only without intervention.

Answer (score 0):

The item that indicates whether a message was successfully recalled or not is a ReportItem.

```
Private Sub Display_TypeOf()

Dim item As Object
Dim msgClass As String

For Each item In ActiveExplorer.Selection

    msgClass = vbCr & vbCr & "Class Is " & item.Class

    If TypeOf item Is mailItem Then
        MsgBox "Subject: " & item.Subject & vbCr & vbCr & "TypeOf Item is mailItem." & msgClass

    ElseIf TypeOf item Is ReportItem Then
        MsgBox "Subject: " & item.Subject & vbCr & vbCr & "TypeOf Item is ReportItem" & msgClass

    ElseIf TypeOf item Is PostItem Then
        MsgBox "Subject: " & item.Subject & vbCr & vbCr & "TypeOf Item is PostItem" & msgClass

    ElseIf TypeOf item Is MeetingItem Then
        MsgBox "Subject: " & item.Subject & vbCr & vbCr & "TypeOf Item is MeetingItem" & msgClass

    ElseIf TypeOf item Is AppointmentItem Then
        MsgBox "Subject: " & item.Subject & vbCr & vbCr & "TypeOf Item is AppointmentItem" & msgClass

    Else
        MsgBox "Subject: " & item.Subject & vbCr & vbCr & "TypeOf Item is not listed in this code." & msgClass

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub OpenRecallDialogForSelectedMessage()

    Dim oSelectedItem As Object
    Dim oSentMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSelectedItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If oSelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No item is selected. Please select a sent message to recall."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TypeName(oSelectedItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set oSentMessage = oSelectedItem
        If oSentMessage.Sent Then
            ' Open the sent message and show the "Recall This Message" dialog
            oSentMessage.Display
            Application.ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "RecallThisMessage"
        Else
            MsgBox "The selected message has not been sent. No need to recall."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "The selected item is not a sent message. Please select a sent message to recall."
    End If
End Sub
```